# powershell repository won't be registered

Tags: windows-10, powershell, repository

I tried to register the PSGallery-Repository to  use cmdlets like `Install-Module`.
So I used:

```
 Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

Powershell told me to use `Register-PSRepository -Default` to register PSGallery-Repository

So I did...

I wanted to proof if it succeeded but:

```
Get-PSRepository
```

returns "No Packagesources found"

Also `Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI` didn't work.

Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?
PowerShell Version is 5.1

Comment: Write it down as an actual answer to your own question and accept it after you can. [`Register-PSRepository`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/register-psrepository?view=powershell-6) supports supplying a proxy. If you weren't able to contact the repository the cmdlet should've shown some kind of error.

Comment: it returned nil so no error message... I don't know why but after I set the proxy into my powershell profile it worked

Answer (score -2):

I missed proxy authentication. I added it to my $profile and now it is working.

Comment: Share a bit what you did to do that and what you added to your profile and it might actually be a decent answer.